# D3.js bar chart by percentage

Tags: d3.js

```js
var data = [
        {month: 'data', A: 20, B: 5, C: 10},
    ];


    var xData = ["A", "B", "C"];

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 0},
            width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .35);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function (c) {
        return data.map(function (d) {
            return {x: d.month, y: d[c]};
        });
    });

    var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    }));

    y.domain([0,
        d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
                function (d) { return d.y0 + d.y;})
        ])
      .nice();

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
            .data(dataStackLayout)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "stack")
            .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                return color(i);
            });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) {
                return d;
            })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x(d.x);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.y + d.y0);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
            })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

.widget {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:350px;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    -background-color: #222D3A;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}

.header{
    background-color: #eee;
    height:40px;
    color:#555;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.chart-container{
    padding:25px;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
    <div class="header">Stacked Bar Chart</div>
    <div id="chart" class="chart-container">

    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to create a d3.js using stacked bar using perctage. Can anyone help me to make this bar graph using percent like this image. Demo would much appreciated. or any reference for this one.

Below code are sample of what im trying to work on.1 single stack bar chart that show percentage. base on the value

[image]

Comment: Since the only thing you're missing is the percentage, please share a working code that already create the stacked bars, and then we can simply add the "percentage" part of it. The thing is, if you show **your** code, we can help you. But if you don't show any code you're just asking people to write code for you.

Comment: Hi, I put my code but I was trying to add the label percent from the right side of the stackbar and use color like gradient. Im a beginner on d3.js pls help. thank you

Comment: That's way better!

Comment: Yah sorry for the late upload of the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We first get the sum of all bars. It's obviously 35 with the data you have, but let's do it without hardcoding:

```
var sum = 0;
dataStackLayout.forEach(d => {
    sum += d[0].y
});
```

Then, we create the text elements:

```
layer.selectAll("foo")
    .data(function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x) + x.rangeBand() + 4;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return (y(d.y + d.y0) + y(d.y0)) / 2;
    })
    .text(d => format(d.y / sum))
```

For positioning the texts, we use the same math of the bars. For the values of the texts, we first set a D3 format:

```
var format = d3.format(".2%")
```

And then we simply divide each `d.y` by the sum.

```
.text(d => format(d.y / sum))
```

Here is your updated code:

```js
var data = [{
  month: 'data',
  A: 20,
  B: 5,
  C: 10
}, ];

var format = d3.format(".2%")


var xData = ["A", "B", "C"];

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 0
  },
  width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .35);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d.month,
      y: d[c]
    };
  });
});

var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
  return d.x;
}));

y.domain([0,
    d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
      function(d) {
        return d.y0 + d.y;
      })
  ])
  .nice();

var sum = 0;

dataStackLayout.forEach(d => {
  sum += d[0].y
});

var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
  .data(dataStackLayout)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "stack")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  });

layer.selectAll("foo")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x) + x.rangeBand() + 4;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return (y(d.y + d.y0) + y(d.y0)) / 2;
  })
  .text(d => format(d.y / sum))


layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y + d.y0);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.widget {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -background-color: #222D3A;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.header {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 40px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.chart-container {
  padding: 25px;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
  <div class="header">Stacked Bar Chart</div>
  <div id="chart" class="chart-container">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much @gerado. anyway is it posible to add gradient using d3.js?

Comment: Yes, but that's a different problem, and I suggest you post another question. Let's keep it 1 problem per question.